# Equivalent to adControl.HasAd in windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ads

In a Windows Phone 8.1 universal app, I could use this Code for a Pub Center ad.

```
//code behind:
if(adControl.HasAd)
{
}

//xaml:
<UI:AdControl x:Name="adControl" AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60" ApplicationId="" AdUnitId="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Foreground="Black" Background="Black"/>
```

But this function isn't avaible for a Silverlight App. Does someone know a equivalent to "adControl.HasAd" in a Windows Phone 8.0 App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent in WP8.0. What you can do though is have your own `bool` and set/unset it with the following two events:

> [`adControl.AdRefreshed:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-adcontrol-silverlight-adrefreshed-event%28v=msads.20%29.aspx)
>
> Raised when the AdControl receives a new ad.

and

> [`adControl.ErrorOccured:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-adcontrol-erroroccurred-event%28v=msads.20%29.aspx)
>
> Raised when the AdControl receives a new ad.

If you just want to collapse the advert when no ad is shown you can also use:

```
adControl.IsAutoCollapseEnabled = true;
```